# I am running 2 jquery cycle slide shows in a table side by side, can't seem to get them to align center

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, show, slide

I put a border of 1 thinking that might help me figure out where I am going wrong. I plan to delete the boarder after I fix the centering issue. The slide show functions perfectly
I just can't seem to get them centered.

I searched google and SO and tried several options suggested in other posts with the margin in the jquery but didn't get anywhere. Any suggestions you can offer would be great!

**Jquery:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 432px; width: 632px; }
.slideshow img { margin:auto; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color:#eee;
display:block; margin:auto; }

</style>

<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="5" table padding="25" align="center">
<tr align="center">
            <td align="middle">move<div class="slideshow">


                </div></td>


            </div></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using tables for layout.  A div approach should be less complimicated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have done, centering elements with margins typically only works if you define the width as well. Also, you only need to define the horizontal margins to auto in order for them to center.

You are centering the image elements inside the slideshow. If you want to center the slideshow then you must apply the margin rules there.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. I'm sure the code is a mess but I wanted to show everything I had already tried. :)  I will also educate myself on the DIV approach ( educating to css is long overdue) and recode.